# How can I equip my site with a "vetting" form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to set up a page within my site that contains a form for a prospective client to fill.

I would then manually inspect the form's results to ensure the prospect is qualified, and then send them a ***temporary*** link to another page that expires in a few hours, or perhaps after one click.

Any advice that can help me towards this goal would result in me thinking you were very cool.

Thanks!!
ms

Comment: Do you have a server for page what language are you using or do you not have a server or have and real knowledge of a language

Comment: Than you for your response MartinWebb,

Comment: I'm actually using Squarespace but have working knowledge of HTML5, CSS3, and plain vanilla Javascript. I suppose this would be done with serverside JS?

Comment: I have answered what I think is your best solution based on your comments see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done server side. The general flow would be that you would submit the html form to the server. Place the data from the form into a server side database. Send an email to the site admin, notifying them that an entry has been made. Then build a control panel where they can view entries and approve them. This would then send an email to the form submitter, grant them access etc.

It may be an easier better approach to use a form service that does most of this for you.

Take a look at:

https://www.formstack.com

If you want to code it your self. You could use a framework such as:

https://firebase.google.com/ (Js)

or

https://github.com/expressjs/express  (Node js)